# Cauchy-Riemann equation and analyticity

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$u(x,y)=\ln(x^2+y^2)$$ be defined on $\mathbb{C}/\{0\}$. Find a harmonic conjugate $v(x,y)$  on some domain $Ω ⊂ \mathbb{C}/{0}$ where $Ω$ is of your choice. Also explain how you justify the analyticity of $u+iv$ on $Ω$.

I used the Cauchy-Riemann equations and I get $$v(x,y)=2\arctan\frac{y}{x}−2\arctan\frac{x}{y}+C$$

I am having trouble figuring out how to choose Ω  how I can justify the analyticity.

Comment: Did you mean $u(x,y) = \ln(x^2+y^2)$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that. Edited

Comment: Your solution seems also to be a bit off. You can check that $v(x,y) = 2 \arctan(y/x) + C $ solves the CR-equations.

Comment: Regarding the choice of $\Omega$. The task gives you the freedom to make it easy on yourself. So you could choose for $\Omega$ the half-plane with $x>0$.